# Создание компаратора для std::list::sort с++

Tags: c++, сортировка, stl

У меня задание написать 
Отсортировать числовую последовательность в порядке возрастания количества делителей её элементов, используя двусвязный список
Я решил использовать std::list
Для сортировки листа std::sort не годится, а вот std::list::sort - самое то
Есть функция определения кол-ва делителей для числа

```
int DoubleList::CountDividers(int num)
{
    int countNum = 0;
    for (int i = 1; i < num; i++)
        if (num % i == 0)
            countNum++;
    return countNum + 1;
}
```

Есть компаратор. По идее туда нужно передавать итератор и по нему получать уже число в листе, так как функция сортировки сама организует итерации

```
bool DoubleList::ComparingDividers(const std::list<int>::iterator &num1, const std::list<int>::iterator &num2)
{
    return (CountDividers(*num1) < CountDividers(*num2));
}
```

Дальше я пытаюсь поместить компаратор в функцию сортировки

```
void DoubleList::Sorting1()
{
    myList.sort(ComparingDividers);
}
```

Программа экстренно завершается
Может кто знает в чём проблема и как правильно здесь организовать компаратор?

Answer (score 1):

Вот как [описывается](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list/sort) компаратор:

```
bool cmp(const Type1 &a, const Type2 &b);
```

Т.е. он сравнивает не итераторы, а сами значения:

```
bool DoubleList::ComparingDividers(const int &num1, const int &num2)
{
    return (CountDividers(num1) < CountDividers(num2));
}
```

Попробуйте так...

**Update**
Я бы ваше задание решал так (алгоритм поиска числа делителей оставил ваш):

```
#include <list>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class Num
{
public:
    Num(int n = 0):n(n)
    {
        d = 0;
        // метод ужасный, но вопрос не в нем...
        for (int i = 1; i < n; i++)
            if (n % i == 0) ++d;
    }
    int value()    const { return n; }
    int dividers() const { return d; }
private:
    int n, d;
};

bool lessD(const Num& a, const Num& b)
{
    return a.dividers() < b.dividers();
}


int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    list<Num> l;
    for(int i = 0; i < 20; ++i)
        l.push_back(20+rand()%200);

    for(auto x: l) cout << x.value() << " ";
    cout << endl;

    l.sort(lessD);

    for(auto x: l) cout << x.value() << "(" << x.dividers() <<") ";
    cout << endl;

}
```

Comment: Вообще мне уже об этом говорили и это скорее всего и есть ключ, но как обратиться тогда к элементам листа, если не по итератору. Уже пробовал

Comment: Алгоритм сам использует компаратор, передавая ему ссылки на элементы. Как он это делает - это его подробности. Вы должны передать ему компаратор, который сравнивает два элемента. Надеюсь, кстати, вы знаете, что если этот компаратор вы делаете членом класса, то он должен быть статическим? И, кстати, метод поиска количества делителей у вас, скажем очень мягко, очень неэффективный...

Comment: А мне не нужно указать в компараторе, что num2 - это следующее числа в листе
Ну просто я сейчас написал, током не ударило, но и не отсортировало. Извините, если я что-то не так говорю, мне не хватает знаний в этом

Comment: Про статический знаю

Comment: См. дополненный ответ (и тут - https://ideone.com/LDeISe)

Comment: Благодарен вам!

Comment: Ну, тогда помечайте ответ как принятый :)